# Manipulating an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am working on one of my assignment questions and am having difficulty manipulating the equation. The equation is as follows, where I have to solve for T, temperature, and the rest of the variables are known.

- Let $\displaystyle \mathrm{D=Density_{[ambient \ air]}, V=Volume, m=m_{Balloon}}$.

The equation is $\displaystyle D=\frac{m+\frac{PMV}{RT}}{V}$.

The equation that our prof. had before solving for the answer was $\displaystyle T=\frac{m+PMV}{DVR}$.

Is that right? I wasn't getting the same equation. If it is right, would someone be able to guide me through it. Here is how I was doing it $$\displaystyle DV=m+\frac{PMV}{RT} \\ DV-m=\frac{PMV}{RT} \\ RT\left[DV-m \right]=PMV \\ T=\frac{PMV}{R\left[DV-m \right]}$$

If more information is needed please let me know, I know I am doing something wrong.

Comment: It seems that your final expression is correct and you made the right steps.

Answer (score 1):

We have the initial equation:

$$\rho_{\text{air}}=\frac{m+(pMV/RT)}{V}$$

Multiplying both sides by $V$:

$$\rho_{\text{air}}V=m+\frac{pMV}{RT} \implies \rho_{\text{air}}V-m=\frac{pMV}{RT}$$

Multiplying both sides by $RT$:

$$RT[\rho_{\text{air}}V-m]=pMV$$

Thus, dividing both sides by $R[\rho_{\text{air}}V - m]$, we have:

$$T=\frac{pMV}{R[\rho_{\text{air}}V-m]}$$

So unless there are other relationships between the variables, your end expression is correct.